# Rocket simulation. Are my equations correct?

Tags: numerical-methods, physics

I am simulating a rocket launch (two dimensions) and I am a little unsure about my implementation of Euler Forward. 
I will only give the $x$ component since $y$ is done the same way. 
I first calculate the acceleration like this:

$$a_x = \frac{F_x - m * g_x * D_x}{m}(1)$$

where $F_x$ is the thrust, $D_x$ is the drag and $g_x$ is the universal law of graviation:

$$g_x = \frac{GMx}{(x^2 +y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}(2)$$

I then use $a_x$ to calculate the position and then the velocity like this:

$$x = x + v*vx*dt (3)$$
where $v$ is the total velocity of the rocket and $vx$ is the $x$ component velocity.

Last I calculate the velocity like this:

$$v_x = v_x + a_x*dt (4)$$

I worry that equation $(3)$ is not right. Can someone confirm that it is right (or wrong)?

Comment: Why not Physics SE?

Comment: They downvote every question I ask. I have tried there and got -2 on this one, so I deleted the question and asked here isntead. I think it's too simple or because it is implementation of Euler question

Comment: Your Euler implementation is wrong, as I already commented in your last deleted question, and your drag computation is wrong, drag is $-C·|v|·v$, thus $d_x=-C·|v|·v_x$. -- Please write first the dynamic part of your simulation as explicit differential equations, then the translation to a numerical solution is almost automatic.

Comment: I have changed the drag, as you point out, and written the equations. I am not sure that I should include the total velocity in the $x$ position update. When I do the fuel required is very small (90 tones) to get it into space. When I take the total speed away, it needs 2000 tones, but when I increase the fuel to 2100, the rocket doesn't lift.

Comment: Did you include that you also need to lift the additional fuel? Look up Ziolkowkis rocket equation, it tells you that a very large majority of the fuel is used to lift fuel.

Comment: Crossposted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/244631/2451

Answer (score 0):

I think it is wrong, because you should not mix the y-contribution of the velocity to x-position.

I would re-write them as :

$v_x = v_x + a_x*dt$             $(3)$

$x = x + v_x*dt$             $(4)$

Comment: I tried it your way but what happens now is first that the amount of fuel needed increases a lot (which is good since it was quite small) but now when I matched the capacity of the rocket (2150 tones of fuel) It doesn't even take off

Comment: Note that this is not the Euler method, but something like perhaps the symplectic Euler method. You need simultaneous updates in unpartitioned Runge-Kutta methods.

Comment: I have also implemented Runge-Kutta but the problem is still the same with those changes

Comment: @LutzL this is Backward Euler Method. This uses the updated acceleration for velocity, and updated velocity for position. If you want to use Forward Euler Method, then you calculate velocity and position before updating acceleration and velocity.

Comment: No, it is also not backward Euler, since the first equation is in long form $v_x[n+1]=v_x[n]+a_x(t[n],x[n],v_x[n])·dt$ using data from sample $n$ in the update, and the second is $x[n+1]=x[n]+v_x[n+1]·dt$ using data from sample $n+1$. Of course, in the indexed form it would be easy to make it into standard Euler via $x[n+1]=x[n]+v[n]·dt$.

Comment: @LutzL with the new time $t[n+1]$, we calculate the new force $F_x$, new drag and new remaining mass, that's why the $a_x$ in the equation represents $a_x[n+1].

Comment: Yes, for the step to compute $v_x[n+2]$. Or you would have to solve the implicit equation $v[n+1]=v[n]+dt·a(t[n+1],x[n]+dt·v[n+1],v[n+1])$.